# How to introduce a while loop in order to calculate monthly interest rate?

Tags: python, function

I have a question where im asked to calculate interest rate of an account after asking user for:

```
P   is  the present value   of  the account.
i   is  the monthly interest    rate.
t   is  the number  of  months.
```

The current code I have is this:

```
def get_value(p, i , t):
    return p * (1 + i) ** t

def main():
    p = float(input("Please enter the current amount of money in your account: "))
    i = float(input("Please enter the monthly interest rate: "))
    t = float(input("Please enter the number of months: "))
    #the while loop would probably go here, but I just dont know how to do it#

    
    future_total = get_value(p, i, t)
    print ("\nAfter", t, "months, you will have $", format(future_total, ".2f"), "in your account.")
    
    
main()
```

But the output is only giving me the final amount after 10 months, how do I implement a loop in order to see how much money would be in the account since month 1?

Comment: Please update your question with your guess as to where a ‘while’ could go.

Comment: If you make the function return the updated value instead of the final value (multiply input by (1+i), then you can loop on the number of months and at each pass store the result, print it, and then pass it as input to the next pass

Answer (score 1):

I would first make a variable called month and set it equal to 1. Then I would use the while loop so that when the month is less than the inputted month, the present value will be updated based on the inputted information. This will print out the money in the account for each month and not just the final value.

```
def get_value(p, i , t):
    month = 1

    while month <= t: 
        p = p * (1 + i) 
        print(month, p)
        month += 1

def main():
    p = float(input("Please enter the current amount of money in your account: "))
    i = float(input("Please enter the monthly interest rate: "))
    t = float(input("Please enter the number of months: "))
    
    print(get_value(p,i,t))
    # future_total = get_value(p, i, t)
    # print ("\nAfter", t, "months, you will have $", format(future_total, ".2f"), "in your account.")
    # print(f'After {t} months, you will have ${future_total} in your account.')
    
main()
```

Comment: Hey kluu thats just outputing some random numbers and not the correct output.

Comment: Hey Alvaro, sorry the exponent should be deleted since it is already being multiplied in the while loop.